# Is there a way to resolve this constraint problem?

Tags: sql, oracle

I  am trying to update an object and I'm getting these errors:

```
SQL Error: 2290, SQLState: 23000
2020-11-26 09:05:18.187 ERROR 6395 --- 
[ XNIO-1 task-62] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
ORA-02290: check constraint (T_MATRICULE) violated

2020-11-26 09:05:18.187 ERROR 6395 --- 
[ XNIO-1 task-62] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : 
HHH000346: Error during managed flush 
[org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (T_MATRICULE) violated

says that there's a **check** constraint on a column, and it was violated. You should check the constraint and ... well, NOT violate it while updating that column.

For example, it might be that column allows values `1` (meaning "on") and `0` (meaning "off") and you tried to update it to `2`.

Comment: I have a constraint for null values so How could I update my values if I want empty value for this foreign key ?

Comment: If you want to allow NULL values for that column, drop the CHECK constraint. If it (a column) is simply set to NOT NULL while creating the table (and thus making an *implicit* check constraint) then `alter table your_table modify column_name null;`

Comment: But as it is a foreign key can I put it to null ?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Foreign key constraint makes sure that you can't insert *invalid values* (that don't exist in the referenced table/column(s)), but it can be left empty (i.e. NULL).

Answer (score 0):

In one of your tables `CHECK` constraint is violated.

You can check the constraint definition using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'T_MATRICULE';
```

Try to avoid inserting/updating values according to `CHECK` constraint validation